# Is it good practice - using EOF exception to detect End of File

Tags: java, serialization, objectinputstream

I am reading from a ObjectInputStream and I do not know number of objects beforehand. So using the EOF exception catch block to detect that END of file has been reached and close the file.

- Is it a good/Safe programming practice?
- If its not a good approach, can it be done in some better manner?

Comment: Can you past the code you're using to read the file ?

Comment: I don't think that exceptions are good for anything but exceptional situations - EOF is not a failure that happens now and then.

Comment: @Boris Treukhov however that is how the API he is using is designed to be used. It throws EOFExcepion at EOS, you have to catch it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have much choice. ObjectInputStream.readObject() throws EOFException when you have run out of objects. Unless you redundantly encode the EOS into the stream yourself you have to catch EOFException.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you are reading objects in a serial manner (which were written in a serial manner i.e. o1, o2, o3) and there is absolutely no other information in the stream.

Two ways you can get around this:

- By writing a list to a file containing the elements and then make the client read a single object, the list
- By writing an int at the start of the stream which denotes the number of objects which the client can expect

If you are sending object stream over a network, it gets a bit hairy, but then again, you'd be better off using RMI than trying to hand-code it.

Comment: @Sanjay My user case is same as u mentioned....
Two workarounds that you have mentioned will not work for me because while I do not know number of objects before hand while I am serializing also.

Comment: @Manoj: Same as what? Reading data over a socket?

Comment: that I am reading objects in a serial manner that were written in a serial manner

Comment: In that case, you can add the objects to a list and write that list. Then when reading, you just do a single `readObject` call and read in the List which will contain all your objects.

Comment: @sanjay My usecase involves writing upto Million objects...If I use the list method, It will crealy overflow the memory.

Comment: I don't think so. Collections store references to objects. If we are talking about 1 million references, it just amounts to around 30MiB of heap space for pointers (assuming 32 bit). You can easily create a VM of heap size upto 1GiB on 32 Windows box. If you still feel short on memory, you can try out the second approach of writing the "count" of the elements before writing the elements themselves. So your code will have `oos.writeInt(someSize); oos.writeObject(o1)` and so on. In the client, just do a `ois.readInt()` and call `ois.readObject` that many times.

Comment: @Sanjay, why not store a special EndOfObjects object at the end? You don't need to to know the total number of objects ahead of time.

Comment: @Dilum Very Nice Idea
worth considering....I dont know number of objects at beginning but I centainly know when I am ending the file...Any caveat should I consider using this.

Comment: @ManojGumber @Dilum Ranatunga the caveat is that you have to defensively code for the case that the file is incomplete. That means catching EOFException. So as you're catching it anyway, why do anything else?

Comment: @Dilum Benifit of having EndOfFile Object is that, if you read End of File object, you are sure that file has been closed properly. But if you do not get EndOfFile Object and instead get EOF exception, you can infer that file is incomplete and act accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Would using the `available()` method be an alternative for you?  Can you rely on the stream not returning zero available before the EoF?

Comment: Have come across many sources that claim that using available is not a reliable way